# XML element removal, just need to delete one element not the parent

Tags: c#, xml

Basically what I am trying to do is remove a VSLOC from the list. I don't want to remove everything that belongs to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GarageNumbers>
  <G554>
    <id>G554</id>
    <VSLOC>V002</VSLOC>
    <VSLOC>V003</VSLOC>
    <VSLOC>V002</VSLOC>
  </G554>
  <G566>
    <id>G566</id>
    <VSLOC>V002</VSLOC>
    <VSLOC>V003</VSLOC>
    <VSLOC>V002</VSLOC>
  </G566>
  <G572>
    <id>G572</id>
    <VSLOC>V001</VSLOC>
    <VSLOC>V002</VSLOC>
  </G572>
</GarageNumbers>
```

So, what I have setup is a combobox that I select a G# from which brings up all the VSLOC associated with it in a Listbox. What I need to do is to select a item from the list box and remove the line from the listbox and from the xml document using a button. I have all this setup but when I hit the button it deletes G554 and all the elements with in.

So if I want to select V002 from the list in G554 I want it to just remove that VSLOC with that innertext.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/xmlData.xml");
            foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("GarageNumbers/G554"))
                if (xNode.SelectSingleNode("VSLOC").InnerText == "V002")
                    xNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xNode);
            xDoc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/xmlData.xml");
```

Comment: Posting the code you are using to remove the Element would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to drill down to the desired elements then remove them. For example, assuming your XML is in an `XElement`, this approach would work:

```
string targetCategory = "G554";
string vsloc = "V002";

xml.Element(targetCategory)
   .Elements("VSLOC")
   .Where(e => e.Value == vsloc)
   .Remove();
```

If you're using an `XDocument` then add the `Root` property: `xml.Root`

Comment: It's better to have asked then not to ask, but I know this may sound weird but what is e? I am sorry, I am new to xml with C#...

Comment: @MikeWoeber no problem. `e => ...` here is a lambda expression and is common with LINQ usage, not just XML. In this case I'm using LINQ to XML. The `e` is an arbitrary parameter name I used which represents any of the elements found by the `Elements` method, and the `Where` method will filter the elements based on this expression. I would suggest researching lambda expressions and LINQ. You might find these links helpful: [Anonymous functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx), [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: e in this case is a parameter that is being passed to the anonymous function. e will represent a resulting object from the .Elements("VSLOC") method.

Comment: I figured it out, I had to switch the e due to it being used by the EventArgs. Thanks for the links that definitely helped out, and I remember learning that while I was in college. Nice refresher!

Answer (score 1):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fname);

var node = xDoc.Descendants("VSLOC")
                .Where(e => (string)e.Parent.Element("id") == "G554")
                .FirstOrDefault();

if (node != null) node.Remove();

xDoc.Save(fname);
```